# Can I fire button click event without firing pageload event?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle, pageload, buttonclick

I have a button on my page and and few textboxes which alters their context on page_load event. when I open the page for the first time it loads random data from a database to textboxes with a function in pageload and also I create those textboxes dynamically. what I want is to make some changes on textboxes texts and click the button than send new context of textboxes to database. But when I click on button, PageLoad event fires again and It regenerates the textboxes and the context of them alter naturally since they are newly created textboxes. I tried to use "if(!Page.isPostBack)" in pageload but then the textboxes and related objects are not being created and they become null.

how can I overcome this problem?
best thing I can think of is to find some way to fire buttons click event without firing PageLoad event, but I dont know how can I do it.

any help would be appreciated;)

Comment: Even the partial Postback will execute page load.

Comment: can you regenerate the `Textbox` on each page load execution? and data assignment to these `Textbox` should be under `!Page.IsPostback`. All you have to do is to keep the IDs of the textbox in `ViewState`  only first time page load and next regeneration of textbox will have the previous stored ID and you also have to store the ID corresponding data in `ViewState`. Makes sense?

Comment: yes it does make sense but I dont know what is ViewState :/ and If I learn to use them somehow can I use it to hold some int or string values?

Comment: Yes offcourse. It can hold object/collection also

Comment: Thanks a lot pal ;) it worked perfect :) using ViewStates solved my problem ;) I am happy thanks to you now :))

Comment: Accept the answer which best addresses your needs.

Comment: I need one more suggestion please. How can I pass a RadioButtonList[] by using viewstate? It says RadioButtonList is not a serializable control. I read you mentioned about IDs, is it the clientID attribute of the objects?and how can I use IDs to send an array of RadioButtonList?

Comment: Suppose you have 10 controls. You can assign some GUID IDs to these controls. while assigning then appending IDs in a list so to keep track of the Ids. Now, while regenerating the control, assign same IDs in same order as mentioned in the list.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to assign a GUID Id to radiobuttonlist and how to regenerate it with this ID :( could you please tell it in a bit more detail.maybe with some code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From Comments

Can you regenerate the `Textbox` on each Page load Execution? and data assignment to these `Textbox` should be under `!Page.IsPostback`. All you have to do is to keep the IDs of the `Textbox` in `ViewState` only first time page load and next regeneration of `Textbox` will have the previous stored ID and you also have to store the ID corresponding data in ViewState. Makes sense?