# Insert a string and click a button on an ASP page from an Android App without opening the page on the phone

Tags: java, android, asp.net, http-post

I want to send a string from an android application and dump it in a textbox and then click a button present in the ASP website without opening that website on the phone (the button and the textbox are both present on the asp web page).

I have control over the website (stuff like `__VIEWSTATE` and the `__EVENTVALIDATION` strings for the ASP Page are available). I would want to know if there is a way to do this using the `__VIEWSTATE` and the `__EVENTVALIDATION` strings. If there is an alternate way, could you please kindly explain me in a step-wise manner.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by this statement? click a button present in the ASP website without opening that website on the phone. How can someone click on the button present in the website without opening the website?

Comment: There are some specific unique strings which are generated when text is filled in the textbox and the button is clicked which when equated to the above keywords, the button is virtually clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I supouse that you would like to start some process on web site after click (for example create/read/ someinformation). But in case you have access to web site source it would be better to create some WCF service or ASHX and use it you can send any data and get result of operation. 
It is not possibe to click on button without open site. or see [Can I fire button click event without firing pageload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124837/can-i-fire-button-click-event-without-firing-pageload-event)

Comment: It was possible to click a button without opening the page through a python script from linux.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124837/can-i-fire-button-click-event-without-firing-pageload-event may be it would help